# Upload a picture with php issues?

Tags: php, image, localhost

so I am just learning PHP and am trying to make it so you can upload a picture. When attempting this on a local host all I get is a picture of a piece of paper being ripped in half (it must be some error/replacement picture). The directory for the image is right its just not being displayed properly. 
thanks

Code:

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root")
  or die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("images", $link)
  or die (mysql_error());

//make variables available
$image_caption = $_POST['image_caption'];
$image_username = $_POST['image_username'];
$image_tempname = $_FILES['image_filename']['name'];
$today = date("Y-m-d");

//upload image and check for image type
//make sure to change your path to match your images directory
$ImageDir ="/Users/JohnSmith/Desktop/images/";
$ImageName = $ImageDir . $image_tempname;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_filename']['tmp_name'],
                   $ImageName)) {

  //get info about the image being uploaded
  list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($ImageName);

      switch ($type) {
    case 1:
      $ext = ".gif";
      break;
    case 2:
      $ext = ".jpg";
      break;
    case 3:
      $ext = ".png";
      break;
    default:
      echo "Sorry, but the file you uploaded was not a GIF, JPG, or " .
           "PNG file.<br>";
      echo "Please hit your browser's 'back' button and try again.";
  }

   //insert info into image table

  $insert = "INSERT INTO images
            (image_caption, image_username, image_date)
            VALUES
            ('$image_caption', '$image_username', '$today')";
  $insertresults = mysql_query($insert)
    or die(mysql_error());

  $lastpicid = mysql_insert_id();

  $newfilename = $ImageDir . $lastpicid . $ext;

  rename($ImageName, $newfilename);

}

?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Here is your pic!</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>Here is the picture you just uploaded to our servers:</p>
<img src="Users/AdamAshwal/Desktop/images/<?php echo $lastpicid . $ext; ?>" align="left">
<strong><?php echo $image_name; ?></strong><br>
This image is a <?php echo $ext; ?> image.<br>
It is <?php echo $width; ?> pixels wide
and <?php echo $height; ?> pixels high.<br>
It was uploaded on <?php echo $today; ?>.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You will need to show some code.

Comment: The image is being stored in the right folder on the desktop, I just can't seem to get it to show in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image isn't being shown because your Desktop is not a public webroot.  Make a directory within your app to store the uploaded images and render them from there.

[JMC Creative's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838837/upload-a-picture-with-php-issues/4838919#4838919) is correct, too -- your image tags don't seem to be looking in the right place for the uploaded images.

On a side note, you have a very obvious SQL injection vulnerability in the code sample that you provided.  All user inputs that are being stored in the database should be sanitized with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).  See [this XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/327/) for a humorous explanation.  An example follows:

```
$image_caption = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['image_caption']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your image src be:

```
<img src="/Users/JohnSmith/Desktop/images/<?php echo $lastpicid . $ext; ?>">
```

The src should be relative to where the script is.

*And don't use `align="left"` in the html tag, use css instead please.*